# Wrong number of arguments (4 for 2) for `border-radius'

Tags: sass, mixins, scss-mixins

this is my scss files structure:
[files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epoDF.jpg)

all of them, imported to main.scss

in _mixins.scss i have a mixin that i want to use it in _buttons.scss, but it fails.

**_mixins.scss**

```
@mixin border-radius(
  $top-left: null,
  $top-right: null,
  $bottom-right: null,
  $bottom-left: null
) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $top-left $top-right $bottom-right $bottom-left;
  -moz-border-radius: $top-left $top-right $bottom-right $bottom-left;
  -ms-border-radius: $top-left $top-right $bottom-right $bottom-left;
  border-radius: $top-left $top-right $bottom-right $bottom-left;
}
```

**_buttons.scss**

```
.header-btn {
  @extend .btn;
  @extend .bg-white;
  @include border-radius(0, 10px, 10px, 10px);
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

this is error message:

```
 error  in ./src/assets/scss/main.scss

 @include border-radius(0, 10px, 10px, 10px);
          ^
      Wrong number of arguments (4 for 2) for `border-radius'
      in C:\Users\M0RT3Z4\Documents\Project\Landing\arda-landing\src\assets\scss\components\_buttons.scss (line 4, column 12)
```

if i copy border radius mixin in _buttons.scss, it works fine and there is no problem.

main.scss is imported to main.js in vue cli 3 project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including Bootstrap in your project and this framework already has a mixin that is called `border-radius`:

```
@mixin border-radius($radius: $border-radius, $fallback-border-radius: false) {
  @if $enable-rounded {
    border-radius: $radius;
  }
  @else if $fallback-border-radius != false {
    border-radius: $fallback-border-radius;
  }
}
```

This mixin, as you can see, has only 2 args and for this the compilator give you that error.

Try to change the name of your mixin 'cause this is only a problem of colliding names.